# Add click event listener to a same button twice with the different functions and want to cancel the first one

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

Add click event listener to a same button twice with the different functions and want to cancel the first one to be triggered always and cancel the second one?

```
 element.addEventListener('click', startDragDrop, false);
 element.addEventListener('click', spyOnUser, false);
```

Is there any way apart from `detachEvent` and how can I make sure always first one is triggered?

P.S. : I cannot remove the code for attaching the second listener and all I can do is make sure always first one is triggered and cancelling the second one which is attached.

Comment: Why can't you use `.removeEventListener('click', startDragDrop, false)`?

Comment: `removeEventListener` requires to pass a reference to existing listener. If you can have it, then it is easiest solution. If not, you can clone element (this will remove existing listeners), insert new element and attach your own listeners

Comment: But how to make sure that always the first event is getting called.